# Using perl Win32::OLE in Windows

Tags: perl, win32ole

I am using Win32::OLE to automate the process of inserting images to a Word document. After some research, I included the following lines:

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft.Word';    # wd  constants
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Office';  # mso constants
```

Then, I included the subroutine as follow:

```
sub insert_picture {
my $document = shift;
my $file     = shift;
my $left     = shift;
my $top      = shift;
my $width    = shift;
my $height   = shift;

my $picture = 
  $document-> Shapes -> AddPicture (
  $file, 
  msoFalse, # link to file
  msoTrue,  # save with document
  $left, $top, $width, $height, 
  $document->ActiveWindow->Selection->{Range}
);
  return $picture;
}
```

When I tried to run the script, I got the error as follow:

Bareword "msoFalse" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at xxx.pl...

Bareword "msoTrue" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at xxx.pl...

The perl version that I am using is 5.14.2, DWIMPerl.

Any idea what is possible problem here? All comments are very much appreciated.

Comment: `use Win32::OLE::Const "Microsoft Office .* Object Library";` see [this PerlMonks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=918381).